# Find frequency of longest consecutive 1's in given range

Tags: c++, algorithm, bit

A query of type [L, R] should return the frequency of **longest consecutive 1's** in a static array in the given range.

Example:

> Arr={1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1}
>
> range[L,R] = [3,11] (indexing starts from 0)
>
> Answer: 2

The maximum length of consecutive 1's is 3: {1,1,1}.

The frequency is **2** since the sequence {1,1,1} can be found twice in the given range. Once from index 4 and once from 9.

Constraints:

> 2<=N<=10^5
> 1<=Q<=10^5

**N= size of array**

**Q=number of range queries**

Input is:
The first line contains the number of elements in the array - N.
The second line contains the elements of said array.
The third line contains the number of queries Q.
The next Q lines contain the range [L, R]  0 <= L <= R < N.

Test:

```
12
1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1
5
3 11
3 10
0 5
1 5
1 4
```

The output should be:

```
2
1
2
1
2
```

I have a solution of O(n^2) but I need a more efficient one.

Comment: Please go read the help pages about what kind of question you can ask here on SO before posting. If you have working code that needs improving you can try Code Review.

Comment: Kenneth, what's "frequency"? And why the frequency for (1,1,1) is 2 ?

Comment: Probably because the sequence 1, 1, 1 can be encountered twice in the given range.

Comment: frequency of {1,1,1} is 2 in array

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify that next time.

Comment: Here is a solution using a segment tree. The total complexity is O(N*LogN + Q*LogN)https://leetcode.com/playground/PTVQvrYb

Comment: it worked!!! But what if i need to do the same for longest consecutive zeros , then what changes i need to do in segment tree.. @A.Hristov

Answer (score 2):

The problem looks trivial as stated:

```
int length = 0, count = 0, i = 0;
while (i < n) {
    while (i < n && seq[i] == 0) i++;
    if (i < n) {
        int start = i;
        while (i < n && seq[i] == 1) i++;
        int size = i - start;
        if (size > length) {
            length = size;
            count = 1;
        } else if (size == length)
            count += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

The idea is simply: for each sequence of 1 if the sequence is longer update length and set count to 1, otherwise if length is equal increment the counter (if length is smaller just do nothing).
It's just one pass over the data: O(n), requires constant memory and can be streamed the data (no random access needed).